# Sending a wrong person due to name mistake to Hell

Tags: jigoku-shoujo

I know how the Hell Link works: you submit the name of the person and when you're ready, you pull the thread in exchange for your soul to Hell.

But here's a twisting question. Let's say you hated this person with someone else's name for something he/she had done to you. Then you would type down this name and send that person to Hell. However, this person is still there and somehow, someone else was sent to Hell due to unreasonable hatred even if you haven't met that person before.

Is it possible that those whose identities were stolen by someone else could be sent to Hell even if it's unreasonable hate?